# How many cron jobs can Ubuntu server handle?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I will setup a server which have 14400 website in it. I will use Ubuntu server 10.10 32-bit. (this is for my learning purposes)

Every website needs cron. So I need 14400 lines of cron.

Can the server handle this huge lists? and what is cron line limit of Ubuntu server (32 and 64-bit)?

Comment: Hilarious question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not about how cron will handle this jobs, but how these jobs will load your server (whether you decide to run them in same time or in different service windows).
It should not be any reason for cron to stop running these jobs, only server load. Also you can reuse /etc/cron.d/ structure to hold separate personal cronjob file for every website, using name convention that similar to site name, so you can easily manage these jobs.

If you going to run them in same time - you may reach limit of open file descriptors.You can control such parameter through /etc/security/limits.conf, or use ulimit.

Comment: It not run all at a time. Thanks for the suggestion.